# How to convert an android project into a library project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-library

I want to convert an android project into a library project.
Can this be done?

I am trying to use this project in another project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Update for Android Studio option

**Convert an app module to a library module**

If you have an existing app module with all the code you want to reuse, you can turn it into a library module as follows:

1. Open the build.gradle file for the existing app module. At the top, you should see the following:
   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
2. Change the plugin assignment as shown here:
   `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
3. Click `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

*That's it. The entire structure of the module remains the same, but it now operates as an Android library and the build will now create an AAR file instead of an APK*

Read more about how to [**Create an Android Library**](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) and how to [**Convert existing project to library project in Android Studio**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614250/convert-existing-project-to-library-project-in-android-studio)

---

> Below steps are for Eclipse

Steps are

```
Right click on project -> property -> Android -> check 'Is library' check box -> OK
```

That's it.

Comment: Is this still valid with Gradle ?

Comment: // Android library
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

Comment: @Abhinav Now updated for Android Studio also. Thank you for pointer.

Answer (score 1):

S.It's possible. For eg: if you take Actionbar sherlock.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/library, it's a library

that has been created . You can import that in properties->Android->library.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using a Mac;

Step One.  Hold down ctrl and tap on the project.
Step Two.  Click Property
Step Three, Android
Step Four, ensure the "Is Library" check box is ticked.