# Can I convert an already existing project into library project in android?

Tags: android

I have an already existing android project, and now I want to use this project as a library project for another project of mine.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Possible uplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598038/how-to-convert-an-android-project-into-a-library-project-in-android

Comment: Just add them in the same workspace, and go to project properties. In the Android tab, add it as a library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have imported both the projects in the same workspace,

**Right Click on your new project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Select the existing project as a library for the new project**

Also, for the existing project :

**Right click on your existing project -> Properties -> Android -> Check 'Is library' check box to enable the project to be used as a library**

Comment: I did exactly the same, but I am facing an error. Let's say the project that I marked as library is "SampleProject" & the project where I want to use it is "HelloWorld". I followed the exat same steps, but HelloWorld project won't compile. Error reads "the container library project refrences non-existing library".

Comment: That seems like eclipse making life hard for you. Remove the reference. Close HelloWorld. Reopen HelloWorld and the add the reference again. Dont forget to clean the project too.

Comment: Restarted eclipse and problem is fixed.

Comment: Haha. Like I said, eclipse does indeed make life hard for you sometimes. Anyway, great that it's working now. Good luck ahead! :)