# Android Studio 1.0 and error "Library projects cannot set applicationId"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

After updating Android Studio to 1.0, I see this error:

> *Error: Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set*
>   *to 'com.super.app' in default config.*

I updated the Gradle plugin as suggested but I did not understand how to fix this.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Based on this [info](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0):

> ApplicationId in Library Projects
>
> You cannot use applicationId to customize the package of a library project. The package name has to be fixed in library projects (and specified as packageName in the manifest). The Gradle plugin did not enforce this restriction earlier.

Removing applicationId variable from the library's `build.gradle` file should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, you drive me to the right direction. I added an answer that explains the "flavour" problem I have.

Comment: @Joel:  i converted the module into a library, but i am not able to find the ApplicationId to remove. ApplicationId  is not dr in build.gradle file. can you tell me where i can find in Android studio 1.0.1

Answer (score 73):

**Thanks to Joel for his correct answer:** I need to remove only 1 line from te `.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.super.app"   <---- remove this line
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

becomes

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.super.app">
...
```

This is the right solution if you don't need to rename the package name of your app. To rename it you need to use "flavours":

```
android {
   ...
   productFlavors {
       flavor1 {
           applicationId 'com.super.superapp'
       }
   }
```

Comment: Too bad two answers can't be checked as you included an example that Joel should have.

Comment: If I remove applicationID line, Can I publish in it Play store?(I mean update) Because there will be no application id for google play.

Comment: @gurkanstack if you remove the line in Gradle file, the name space defined in AndroidManifest.xml "package" will be used for pubblication.

Answer (score 4):

Libraries can't set `applicationId` and if you are working in a multi-module project and picking up `flavors` from a separate file , none of the above answers will work. For a modularized app, you need the following steps -

Create a `flavors.gradle` file in project root directory

```
 ext.flavorConfig = { // 1
    
        flavorDimensions "pricing"
        productFlavors {
            free {
                dimension "pricing"
                ext.myApplicationIdSuffix = '.free' // 2
            }
            paid {
                dimension "pricing"
                ext.myApplicationIdSuffix = '.paid'
            }
        }
    
        productFlavors.all { flavor -> // 3
            if (flavor.hasProperty('myApplicationIdSuffix') && isApplicationProject()) {
                flavor.applicationIdSuffix = flavor.myApplicationIdSuffix
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    def isApplicationProject() { // 4
        return project.android.class.simpleName.startsWith('BaseAppModuleExtension')
     
    }
```

- In 1 we export a closure so that we can use it in our modules’ build.gradle files.
- In 2 we define a custom myApplicationIdSuffix property. We cannot simply have applicationIdSuffix as it is not possible to use it in library modules (build would fail if you did).
- In 3 we iterate over created flavors and set applicationIdSuffix if we detect that it’s an application module only.
- 4 is a way to check where this closure is being used.

All that’s left is to use this closure in our modules’ `build.gradle` files. E.g. in application module this would look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/flavors.gradle"

android {
    // other config...

    with flavorConfig
}
```

If this isn't clear, you can check out [this article](https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/modularizing-your-flavored-android-project-5db75c59fb0d) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase it helps some one :

When i imported an eclipse project into android studio,i got an error ::

***"Error:Application and test application id cannot be the same"***

Strange though,but i looked into the build.gradle and found the two placeholders,one for the application and other for testapplication.

I removed the testApplicationId from that as is suggested in this post and this helped me resolve the issue.

Note: This explaination is not related to the errors posted in this question,but might help someone who is getting a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define applicationId for your lib.
But incase you want to use an identifier in your build file, which will give you, your library package name, you can define a variable for the module and then use the value as required.

eg : Library's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def libraryGroupId = 'com.google.example'
def libraryArtifactId = project.getName()
def libraryVersion = '1.1'
```

Also, you can use the value below as needed in your build file itself in lib.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "$libraryVersion"
    resValue "string", "Library", libraryGroupId"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a modular application, the `applicationId` variable should be in the `build.gradle` file of the main module, but the `applicationId` should not be in the `build.gradle` file of the other module or modules.

For example :

Main Module build.gradle

```
applicationId "com.example.exampleProject"
```

Other Module / Modules build.gradle

```
group = 'com.example.exampleOtherModule'
```