# android studio 1.0 Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to '' in default config

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aviary

I set the "applicationId aviarySdkPackageName" in Aviary's build.gradle.
I updated the android studio and it shows error: Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to '' in default config.
But after I removed this line, there are many errors in Aviary.
Do you know what should I do ?

Comment: You should post errors first, after that we'll figure something out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio 1.0 and error "Library projects cannot set applicationId"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374933/android-studio-1-0-and-error-library-projects-cannot-set-applicationid)

Comment: remove the line applicationId aviarySdkPackageName from the library grade file. It will work w/o problems

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to remove the **applicationId** parameter from the **defaultConfig** in your **library's build.gradle** files.

That should work

Comment: removing applicationId is giving `error: element value must be a constant expression` R.java not found to import. can you solve this ?

Comment: I think your error is not caused by the deletion of the applicationId. Try making a "clean project", if that doesnt work try restoring the applicationId  and see if the problem persist (just to descart that the error is due to the deletion of the applicationId).

Answer (score 0):

```
   # ApplicationId in Library Projects#

    You cannot use applicationId to customize the package of a library project. The package name has to be fixed in library projects (and specified as packageName in the manifest). The Gradle plugin did not enforce this restriction earlier.
```