# how to use my android project in android studio as a library in other projects?

Tags: android

I have developed an android application in android studio.I want to use this as my library in other projects.Is there any way to use this project as a library?

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23765263/1697047

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your app's build.gradle  file

apply plugin: 'YOUR LIBRARY PACKAGE NAME'