# Converting Android application to android library gives Error: constant expression required

Tags: java, android, android-library, android-application-class

I have an Android application which I wish to convert to a library to use in another application. I have changed `com.android.application` to `com.android.library` in the apply plugin section in gradle file. Removed application id. Removed the Launcher intent in the Launcher application of library. But when I build this project I get several errors which require constant expression like in `R.id.imageButton` .

Some other posts indicate that ids are used inside switch cases which require 'constants'. So a workaround may be replacing switch cases with if-else constructs. But is the only way? Also, if yes, why are ids not treated as constants now that I am switching my project to a library instead of application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614250/convert-existing-project-to-library-project-in-android-studio

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i have seen the link, it mostly tells us to update the plugin in gradle file. As mentioned I did that and on rebuilding I get those "constant expression required" errors.

Answer (score 1):

you need covert `switch` into `if/else` code block。

reference:[Non-constant Fields in Case Labels](http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields)