# Android convert project to library project

Tags: android

I am trying to convert an Android Studio project as a library.

What is the best way to do this and the steps I need to follow?

What file can I remove from that library project, so that the library look cleaner?

Comment: This post might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614250/convert-existing-project-to-library-project-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanks I will read it later

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An Android library is structurally the same as an Android app module. **It can include everything needed to build an app, including source code, resource files, and an Android manifest**. However, instead of compiling into an APK that runs on a device, an Android library compiles into an Android Archive (AAR) file that you can use as a dependency for an Android app module. Unlike JAR files, AAR files can contain Android resources and a manifest file, which allows you to bundle in shared resources like layouts and drawables in addition to Java classes and methods.

**Convert an app module to a library module**

Open the build.gradle file for the existing app module. At the top, you should see the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Change the plugin assignment as shown here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Also in this file, you have to delete this line

```
applicationId "your.application.id"
```

Click Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Check this for more details https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: after changing it, i am getting the following error `No resource identifier found for attribute 'labelerClass' in package 'com.googlecode.android.widgets.MyClass'`. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You forgot to mention that he should delete the "applicationId" too from build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You need to do THREE things :

1- change the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in the `build.gradle` of the module to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

2-delete `applicationId "your.application.id"` in the module's `build.gradle`

3-remove `<application` and it its content from your module's `AndroidManifest.xml` file

4-also remove the resources in `mipmap` directories and the `themes` and `colors.xml` (or any other resource file that might conflict with the parent or app module) to avoid any surprises and crashes when using this library module from a module that has the same files.(I have wasted 4 hours to know the reason of app crash at startup with no helpful logs).