# Gradle Sync failed on including libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a Parent android project that has two buttons. I also have two android Child projects. Each button click on the Parent project is supposed to open one of these Child projects. I searched online and found that I can combine all three projects by making the Child projects as libraries and include them in the Parent (as libraries). I've converted the two child projects in libraries using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614250/convert-existing-project-to-library-project-in-android-studio) link. After converting, I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk) video to add the child libraries to the parent android project. However, Gradle Sync fails with the following error:

```
Error: Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libraries:ChildProject2
```

This error is caused by the following line in build.gradle (of parent project):

```
compile project(':libraries:ChildProject2')
```

I am new to android and don't know how to solve this issue. I have tried the link below, however, I can't solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

link: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dependencies-failing-to-resolve-due-to-configuration-dependencies/1617

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:ChildProject2'
```

Build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.smartfarmer.parentproject"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':libraries:ChildProject2')//, configuration: "compile")
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle files and settings.gradle file

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have edited my question above to add the code you requested.

Comment: Are you using the android-gradle plugin v 3.x ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes. Its Gradle version 3.3

Comment: Try to use implementation project(':libraries:ChildProject2') instead of compile project(':libraries:ChildProject2')

Comment: It gives an error stating method implementation not found. It doesn't autocomplete implementation, making me think it is not found in this version.

Comment: Sorry Umar, my bad. I read 3.3 , but I was thinking about gradle-plugin v3, not gradle v3 (don't confuse them, are diffrent). You can't use this implementation()