# Integration of Android Native module with existing Xamarin Native Project

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

We have teams which are working on different different technologies. Currently struggling with integration of android native module (Developed in android native language) with existing Xamarin android project.

Actually I got one way that we can convert android native project as a library. This library can integrate to Xamarin project. 
I had gone through below links

1. [Convert existing project to library project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614250/convert-existing-project-to-library-project-in-android-studio)
2. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/ ( Integration of android library in xamarin project)

Is this the correct way or do we have any alternate way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way or do we have any alternate way to achieve it?

The document [Using Native Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/) is talking about how to use `.so` file (native libraries) in `Xamarin.Android`, here is the [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/SanAngeles_NDK/).

It is recommended that using  [Binding Java Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/). You could convert your android native project to a `.jar` or `.arr` file, then you could refer to  [Binding a .JAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/) or [Binding an .AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/).

If there is any problem when you trying binding  Java Library, you could refer to  [Troubleshooting Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/).