# Convert existing project to framework in ios similar to gradle in Android

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, object, frameworks

I have a project in Android and similar project in ios. I need to convert whole project into library in both platforms.

I can convert whole Android project into library by making changes in gradle file:

```
// apply plugin: ‘com.android.application’
apply plugin: ‘com.android.library’
```

Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23765263/217586

However in iOS project I need to add a framework target and then link all project files within it.

I was wondering that is there any concise way to achieve this in Xcode? May be using xcodebuild?